# std::map::find()

Tags: c++, dictionary, find, operator-overloading

I have a simple struct which i'm using as a key in a std::map

```
struct PpointKey{
        unsigned int xp,yp; //pixel coordinates

        unsigned int side;

        PpointKey(unsigned xp,unsigned yp,unsigned side=5):xp(xp),yp(yp),side(side)
        {}  


        bool operator==(const PpointKey& other) const{
                const unsigned int x = other.xp;
                const unsigned int y = other.yp;

                return ((x>=xp && x<=xp+side) && (y>=yp && y<=yp+side));
        }   

        bool operator<(const PpointKey& other) const{

                const unsigned int x = other.xp;
                const unsigned int y = other.yp;

                const unsigned  other_distance_2 = x*x + y*y;

                const unsigned  this_distance_2 = this->xp*this->xp + this->yp * this->yp;

                return this_distance_2 < other_distance_2;
        }   
};
```

What I would like to achieve is to use the find() to access the map with a key that has its xp,yp attributes within a `side` distance. In other words, if I have an (x,y) tuple, I would like to find inside the map the first PpointKey that fulfils the condition inside the operator== function

```
return ((x>=xp && x<=xp+side) && (y>=yp && y<=yp+side));
```

Is this possible using find? I'm getting map.end(), so I would like to check wheter the find () function uses the operator==. Maybe the search algorithm would be better?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have in mind that `std::map` uses only `operator <`. Two keys are considered equal if neither of them is less than the other.

Answer (score 1):

The `find` function of `map` does not use the `operator==`.

However you can use `std::find`, passing in the `begin()` and `end()` iterator of `map`. It will simply iterate through the sequence one at a time and yield the first object that matches (complexity is linear).

The issue you encounter is due to the fact that you have abused operator overload. The problem here is that the common definition of `operator==` is:

```
T operator==(T lhs, T rhs)
{
  return !(lhs < rhs) && !(rhs < lhs);
}
```

And this is not the case with your definition, thus you cannot substitute one for the other.

It would be best if you used traditional functions with expressive names rather than operator overloading, it would be less misleading. Note that `map` and `std::find` allow you to pass suitable predicate objects, you don't need to overload the operators to use them.

Comment: But `std::find()` would operator on `std::pair<const Key,Value>::`, not on `Key` alone. So `std::find_if()` with the appropriate predicate should be used, right?